# Single-function listeners using lambda

Tags: kotlin

With all the well-known single-function listeners we can use a simpler lambda notation

```
view.setOnClickListener { do() }
```

instead of the original, longer Java way of

```
view.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
  override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    do()
  }
})
```

But what exactly makes this work? I tried to do the same with my own listener:

```
private var listener: OnCopyPasteClickListener? = null

interface OnCopyPasteClickListener {
  fun onPasteClick(text: String)
}

fun setOnCopyPasteClickListener(onCopyPasteClickListener: OnCopyPasteClickListener) {
  listener = onCopyPasteClickListener
}
```

and while the long approach works just fine:

```
copypaste.setOnCopyPasteClickListener(object : CopyPasteMenu.OnCopyPasteClickListener {
  override fun onPasteClick(text: String) {
    do(text)
  }
})
```

I can't make it accept the short one:

```
copypaste.setOnCopyPasteClickListener {
  do(it)
}
```

The IDE gives a type mismatch error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, if you have only one function to be invoked, I recommend you use Kotlin Callback.

```
typealias OnDoWorkListener = ((String) -> Unit)

class Work {
    var doWork: OnDoWorkListener? = null

    fun doSomething() {
       doWork?.invoke("Message Here")
    }
}
```

And in your function, you just set the callback to it

```
fun main() {
   val work = Work()

   work.doWork = {
       Log.d("WORK", "This gets called from the `work` object. Message: $it")
   }

   work.doSomething();
}
```

We can also use function to set the listener as well.

```
class Work {
    var doWork: OnDoWorkListener? = null

    fun doSomething() {
       doWork?.invoke("Message Here")
    }

    fun setOnWorkListener(listener: OnDoWorkListener) {
       doWork = listener
    }
}


fun main() {
   val work = Work()
   work.setOnWorkListener { 
       Log.d("WORK", "This gets called from the `work` object. Message: $it")
   }
   work.doSomething()
}
```

Comment: Sorry, you both suggested basically the same and I can only accept one answer. I like this `typealias` syntactic sugar to masquerade the difference. There is just one small problem in the IDE, it erroneously reports the implicit `it` shadowed in the listener but it actually isn't, it works just fine. Or we can use an explicit parameter instead of `it` and then it doesn't complain any more. Thanks.

Comment: Sure! we can specify it like this `work.setOnWorkListener { yourName ->  callSomething() }`

Comment: Yes, of course, that's what I did. Still, it isn't nice of the IDE to complain.

Comment: If you want to mark it as an unused parameter you can specify with an underscore ( _ ) like this `work.setOnWorkListener { _ -> callSomething() }`

Comment: No, I need it. The only problem is that Android Studio underlines it and suggests an unnecessary fix. The code is perfect and it works perfect as is.

Answer (score 1):

[Higher order functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) make this work:

> Kotlin functions are first-class, which means that they can be stored
>   in variables and data structures, **passed as arguments to** and returned
>   from other higher-order functions. You can operate with functions in
>   any way that is possible for other non-function values.

From the [same page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter):

> **Passing a lambda to the last parameter**
>
> In Kotlin, there is a convention that if the last parameter of a
>   function accepts a function, a lambda expression that is passed as the
>   corresponding argument can be placed outside the parentheses:
>
> ```
> val product = items.fold(1) { acc, e -> acc * e }
> ```
>
> If the lambda is the only argument to that call, the parentheses can
>   be omitted entirely:
>
> ```
> run { println("...") }
> ```

Knowing this, a possible update on your class would look like:

```
class CopyPaste {
    private var listener: (String) -> Unit = {}

    fun setOnCopyPasteClickListener(onCopyPasteClickListener: (String) -> Unit) {
        listener = onCopyPasteClickListener
    }

    fun doCopyPaste(value: String) {
        listener.invoke(value)
    }
}

fun main() {
    val copyPaste = CopyPaste()
    copyPaste.setOnCopyPasteClickListener { println(it) }
    copyPaste.doCopyPaste("ClipboardContent!")
}
```

The class `CopyPaste` stores the listener, which is a function that takes a `String` parameter and does not return anything. Its function `setOnCopyPasteClickListener` accepts a function with the same signature as the `listener` property and at the end `doCopyPaste` accepts a `String` parameter and passes it to the stored function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, just after I posted, I searched for more thoughts and found this thread: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770 This is indeed a debated limitation as it currently only applies to Java, not Kotlin itself. There is also a suggestion there that gives almost the required simplicity:

```
interface OnCopyPasteClickListener {
  fun onPasteClick(text: String)

  companion object {
    inline operator fun invoke(crossinline op: (text: String) -> Unit) =
      object : OnCopyPasteClickListener {
        override fun onPasteClick(text: String) = op(text)
      }
  }
}
```

and then, thanks to this overloaded operator, it can be called as:

```
copypaste.setOnCopyPasteClickListener(CopyPasteMenu.OnCopyPasteClickListener { text ->
  do(text)
})
```

But as the suggested answers offer a more idiomatic solution, I'll accept one of those, I only wanted to include this approach here for reference.